# tkinter entry variable from function

Tags: python, tkinter, global, tkinter-entry

This should be easy but I am suffering search fatigue for the answer I need. The code below pops up an input window. I make entries into the entry fields and the function show_entry_fields() gets the input and the window closes. I then want to use the new entry variables in code that follows but they revert back to their initial, global values. I define them as global so I can use them throughout the script, but the entry function fails to change them. How can I get input from users that is then available to the rest of the program?

```
import tkinter as tk

site = 'cats'
score = 100

def show_entry_fields():
    site = e1.get()
    score = e2.get()
    master.destroy()
    #print(site,score)


master = tk.Tk()
master.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
tk.Label(master, text="website").grid(row=0)
tk.Label(master, text="Image Ranking").grid(row=1)

e1 = tk.Entry(master)
e2 = tk.Entry(master)

e1.insert(0,site)

e1.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='EW')
e2.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='EW')

tk.Button(master, text='Quit', command=master.quit).grid(row=3,  column=0, sticky='W', pady=4)
tk.Button(master, text='Go!', command=show_entry_fields).grid(row=3, column=1, sticky='W', pady=4)
master.mainloop( )

print(site, score)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this solve the problem?

```
def show_entry_fields():
    global site, score, master
    site = e1.get()
    score = e2.get()
    master.destroy()
```

At least the print at the end of the program is printing the right answer.

Comment: Yes that does it. But I understood that declaring the variables at the start made them global. I've gone back and explicitly done that at the beginning and it also works. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're welcome! Just a little advice: try to avoid global variables, or at least only use `global` where you need it. It will avoid conflicts in the future! By the way: if the answer was helpful, please mark it as accepted (click the 'V' left of the answer) and/or upvote it (with the up-arrow). That way, others will know there is a valid answer to your problem!