# Global variable to available

Tags: python, function, tkinter

I've got an issue with my code I'm simply unable to work out the error in.
Similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30067866/tkinter-entry-variable-from-function#). However, trying the solution did not provide me with an answer.
I've declared the variable `file_location` as global in order to have it avaible for the later code. This was the answer for aforementioned question.
I know it should be avoided, but with my experience level I do not see any other way.

**Goal:** I wish to write `file_location` to `entry`.

Running the code yields error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Data\Python Scripts\PDFtoText with GUI.py", line 87, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Data\Python Scripts\PDFtoText with GUI.py", line 82, in main
    app = Application()
  File "C:\Data\Python Scripts\PDFtoText with GUI.py", line 14, in __init__
    self.initUI()
  File "C:\Data\Python Scripts\PDFtoText with GUI.py", line 61, in initUI
    entry.insert(0, file_location)
NameError: name 'file_location' is not defined
>>>
```

Code as follows:

```
from tkinter import Tk, W, E
from tkinter.ttk import Frame, Button, Entry, Style
from tkinter import filedialog as fd


class Application(Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

        
    def initUI(self):
        
        def select_file():
            global file_location
            file_location = fd.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/C:/Users",title = "Select file",filetypes = (("PDF files","*.pdf"),("all files","*.*")))
            #print(file_location)           #Used for debugging and validating paths.


        self.master.title("PDF to Text Convertor")
        Style().configure("TButton", padding=(0, 5, 0, 5),
            font='serif 10')

        self.columnconfigure(0, pad=3)
        self.columnconfigure(1, pad=3)
        self.columnconfigure(2, pad=3)
        self.columnconfigure(3, pad=3)

        self.rowconfigure(0, pad=3)
        self.rowconfigure(1, pad=3)
        self.rowconfigure(2, pad=3)
        self.rowconfigure(3, pad=3)
        self.rowconfigure(4, pad=3)


        btnSelect = Button(self, text="Select File", command=select_file)
        btnSelect.grid(row=1, column=0)

        entry = Entry(self)
  
        entry.insert(0, file_location)
        entry.grid(row=0, columnspan=4, sticky=W+E)
        
        btnClear = Button(self, text="Clear text")
        btnClear.grid(row=1, column=1)
      
        btnConvert = Button(self, text="Convert")
        btnConvert.grid(row=1, column=2)

        btnClose = Button(self, text="Close", command = self.master.destroy)
        btnClose.grid(row=1, column=3)

        

        self.pack()



def main():

    root = Tk()
    app = Application()
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question you mentioned is different from your issue.

Your code insert them firstly.Even though you "solve" this issue by previous answer, the path wouldn't be change after you select a file

You could insert the path in the function `select_file`(Also could avoid using global variable.):
Remove the line:

```
entry.insert(0, file_location)
```

Change your `select_file` function to:

```
def select_file():
    file_location = fd.askopenfilename(initialdir="/C:/Users", title="Select file",
                                       filetypes=(("PDF files", "*.pdf"), ("all files", "*.*")))
    # print(file_location)           #Used for debugging and validating paths.
    if file_location: # insert here.
        entry.insert("insert", file_location)
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked perfectly. Also, good to learn how toa void global in this case. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should declare a global variable before any other in Python. Also there are another bug in your code. You call `file_location` before you initialize it. You should do `select_file()` before calling `entry.insert(0, file_location)`

```
from tkinter import Tk, W, E
from tkinter.ttk import Frame, Button, Entry, Style
from tkinter import filedialog as fd

file_location = None #Declare it here

class Application(Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

        
    def initUI(self):
        
        def select_file():
            global file_location
            file_location = fd.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/C:/Users",title = "Select file",filetypes = (("PDF files","*.pdf"),("all files","*.*")))
            #print(file_location)           #Used for debugging and validating paths.


        self.master.title("PDF to Text Convertor")
        Style().configure("TButton", padding=(0, 5, 0, 5),
            font='serif 10')

        self.columnconfigure(0, pad=3)
        self.columnconfigure(1, pad=3)
        self.columnconfigure(2, pad=3)
        self.columnconfigure(3, pad=3)

        self.rowconfigure(0, pad=3)
        self.rowconfigure(1, pad=3)
        self.rowconfigure(2, pad=3)
        self.rowconfigure(3, pad=3)
        self.rowconfigure(4, pad=3)


        btnSelect = Button(self, text="Select File", command=select_file)
        btnSelect.grid(row=1, column=0)

        entry = Entry(self)
  
        entry.insert(0, file_location)
        entry.grid(row=0, columnspan=4, sticky=W+E)
        
        btnClear = Button(self, text="Clear text")
        btnClear.grid(row=1, column=1)
      
        btnConvert = Button(self, text="Convert")
        btnConvert.grid(row=1, column=2)

        btnClose = Button(self, text="Close", command = self.master.destroy)
        btnClose.grid(row=1, column=3)

        

        self.pack()



def main():

    root = Tk()
    app = Application()
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: "You should declare a global variable before any other in Python" - no, it just has to have been assigned a value before you try to use it, that's all.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Yes, but no. Technically it will work as you say. But according to Python formatting, constants&globals are required to place above code, on the module level. It's just something I like to see.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply define self.file_location:

```
from tkinter import Tk, W, E
from tkinter.ttk import Frame, Button, Entry, Style
from tkinter import filedialog as fd


class Application(Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.file_location = None
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        def select_file():
            self.file_location = fd.askopenfilename(initialdir="/C:/Users", title="Select file",
                                               filetypes=(("PDF files", "*.pdf"), ("all files", "*.*")))
            # print(file_location)           #Used for debugging and validating paths.

        self.master.title("PDF to Text Convertor")
        Style().configure("TButton", padding=(0, 5, 0, 5),
                          font='serif 10')

        self.columnconfigure(0, pad=3)
        self.columnconfigure(1, pad=3)
        self.columnconfigure(2, pad=3)
        self.columnconfigure(3, pad=3)

        self.rowconfigure(0, pad=3)
        self.rowconfigure(1, pad=3)
        self.rowconfigure(2, pad=3)
        self.rowconfigure(3, pad=3)
        self.rowconfigure(4, pad=3)

        btnSelect = Button(self, text="Select File", command=select_file)
        btnSelect.grid(row=1, column=0)

        entry = Entry(self)

        entry.insert(0, self.file_location)
        entry.grid(row=0, columnspan=4, sticky=W + E)

        btnClear = Button(self, text="Clear text")
        btnClear.grid(row=1, column=1)

        btnConvert = Button(self, text="Convert")
        btnConvert.grid(row=1, column=2)

        btnClose = Button(self, text="Close", command=self.master.destroy)
        btnClose.grid(row=1, column=3)

        self.pack()


def main():
    root = Tk()
    app = Application()
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```